# How to reference a remote JS file path

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

How can I reference a remote JS file like Google Maps API url or any remote JS file path into my JSF 2.0 page?

What I understand is that this code

```
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>JSF 2 outputScript example</h1>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="example.js" />
</h:body>
```

will be rendered like this

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>JSF 2 outputScript example</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="/JavaServerFaces/faces/javax.faces.resource/example.js?ln=js">
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I reference external JS files if it by default points to `src="/JavaServerFaces/faces/javax.faces.resource/`?

Comment: Maybe just use normal html tag `<script src="http://page.com/external.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include them the normal html way, e.g.:

```
<h:head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places..."
        type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</h:head>
```

You can mix html tags and JSF tags in a facelet. Put it in the head section of your page.